# Matrix doesn't show data after reading from excel sheet

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to open data from excel and than load them to the matrix, but when I do it, I cannot see values, but just the word "numeric".

Console Output:

```
> c<-readWorksheetFromFile("test.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = FALSE)
> c
  Col1 Col2
1  3.0  4.0
2  5.0  6.0
3  7.0  8.0
4  8.0  9.0
5 10.0 11.0
6 11.7 12.7
7 13.4 14.4
> matrix(c,7,2)
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
[2,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
[3,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
[4,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
[5,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
[6,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
[7,] Numeric,7 Numeric,7
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `as.matrix` to convert a `data.frame` to `matrix`

```
as.matrix(c)
```

It is better to not name object names with functions